# Angular Universal - get to know client OS

Tags: angular-universal

I wonder is there any way to get to know what is client OS in order I could render different images for desktops(1600px of width), tablets(1366px) and phones(736px)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below mentioned npm package for it:

[Device Detector for Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector)

Also the demo for same is being given at:

[Demo for Device Detector Angular](https://koderlabs.github.io/ngx-device-detector/demo/)

Comment: Thanks Sunny!
Have you ever heard about Server Side Rendering? Take a look at it once you got a chance.

Comment: Sorry! The above answer is not applicable in server side rendering (Angular Universal). Thanks for bringing this into notice. Will look for other alternatives if any and will update here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from the HTTP Request Header `user-agent` and then from your server serve the passing data.

Comment: Thanks, I've already done it: 
const req = this._injector.get(REQUEST);
this.ua = req.headers['user-agent'];